# Should you always use an ExecutorService instead of starting your own thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

With JDK >= 1.5, should the preferred way to start a thread always be an Executor or Executor Service, or are there still reasons to prefer to use a Thread.start if you don't need what an ExecutorService provides?

For syncronized, I used to think that using the new Lock implemenations was preferred, until I was [explained otherwise](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/servlets/ReadMsg?list=dev&msgNo=2233). So I'm wondering the same thing about Executors. Are they just a way of handling more complex cases, or should they be the standard choice?

Comment: Both great answers, but I had to give the accepted one that brought up the comparison with Vector and Hashtable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally, since Java 5, I've completely left over `Thread` and `ThreadGroup`, as they provide way less customization and functionality than `ExecutorService`.

When using `ExecutorService`, I know I can use `Callable`, I know I can (with a little overhead) schedule repeated tasks. As a consequence, I consider direct instantiation of `Thread` objects deprecated code, as `Vector` and `Hashtable` are.

Answer (score 12):

[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) at least clearly states in section 6.2.:

> The primary abstraction for task execution in the Java class libraries is *not* `Thread`, but `Executor`. [...]
>
> *Using an Executor is usually the easiest path to implementing a producer-consumer design in your application.*

Answer (score 2):

Writing correct multi-threaded code is very difficult.  The beauty of the Executor framework is that it implements most of the heavy lifting that developers will encounter and only requires that you implement Callable or Future and program to the java.util.concurrent API.  IMHO it results in much more readable code and presents many fewer opportunities to incorrectly implement it due to the complexity of properly managing threads.